# How exactly does Project Astoria manage to run Android / Java Apps on Windows (Mobile)

Tags: java, android, windows-10-mobile

I'm interested in learning a bit more about Microsoft's [Project Astoria](https://dev.windows.com/en-us/uwp-bridges/project-astoria), a Tool / SDK that will let you convert Android apks to Windows Universal Apps and run them on Windows 10 Mobile devices.

I do get that certain services like maps or access to sensors will be mapped the the Windows equivalent.

But how exactely does Microsoft make Java code work on Windows Arm devices where there's no Java installed like you can do on regular x86 devices?

Comment: Most Android devices are using the exact same CPUs as Windows Phone devices and also have no JVM (they have Dalvik/ART runtime).

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is something like [Jazelle DBX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jazelle) (from the linked Wikipedia) *Jazelle DBX (Direct Bytecode eXecution) allows some ARM processors to execute Java bytecode in hardware as a third execution state alongside the existing ARM and Thumb modes.*

There were also [JavaStations](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/JavaStation-HOWTO/whatischapter.html) (Network Computers) that ran byte-code natively.

Comment: Unlikely to be relevant, as Android is based on Dalvik byte code, not Java.

Comment: @fadden OP asked for Android/Java apps. I realize Dalvik isn't Java byte code, but conceptually there's no reason it couldn't be transputed (I remember transmeta).